# Collaborative editing:Using Rudel to connect to a Gobby process

Tags: gobby, rudel

I would like to set a server to host a Gobby process https://gobby.github.io/.
It would host latex files for example

And I was thinking of using rudel https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Rudel to connect to the server and compile the tex file locally.

The Gobby process allows for multiple users to edit a file at the same time.

The rudel package seem to have been abandoned no new recent update.

I have been able to connect two rudel sessions for collaborative editing but this session is not secure on the one that use the Gobby process is.
Yet could not use rudel to connect to the gobby process. The function `join-session` seem to get stuck on “Joining (new)”.

Have anyone tried and succedded to connect rudel to a Gobby process? Any help is welcome.

Comment: From what I remember from [Bug#23996](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23996), I didn't manage to connect to a Gobby server either. AFAIK, the GNU ELPA repo has the latest version of rudel, patches welcome.

Comment: Also if you're using Rudel from GNU ELPA and it doesn't work, please `M-x report-emacs-bug` (and try and give as much info as possible to reproduce the problem).

Comment: Many thanks for the info. I will give feedback whenever things go wrong.